# No contiene una definición pública para 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, mvc, controller, model-view-controller

Me parace el siguiente error:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error   CS1579  La instrucción foreach no puede funcionar en variables de tipo "Companis" porque "Companis" no contiene ninguna definición de instancia pública para "GetEnumerator"

Mi modelo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ArcsaSite.Models
{
    public class Companis
    {
        public IEnumerable<vVentas> vVentas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi controlador:

```
public ActionResult Rxo()
{
    using (XdEntities ctx = new XdEntities())
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        var model = new XdSite.Models.Companis();
        model.vVentas = ctx.vVentas.ToList();                
        return View("~/Views/Home/ventas.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

Mi vista:

```
@model XdSite.Models.Companis
@using XdSite.Configuration;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ventas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)

{
    <li><a href="/Company/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdeInforme)/@Cleanurls.ToFriendlyUrl(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre))" title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</a></li>

}
```

Cualquier ayuda al error: gracias

Comment: Estas intentando iterar sobre el objeto de la clase y no sobre el atributo `vVentas` por eso te da ese error.

Comment: en la vista tiene que ser `@model IEnumerable<XdSite.Models.Companis>`  en lugar de `@model XdSite.Models.Companis `

Comment: no me funciona ahora dice que no existe el viewbag y cosas asi

Comment: cual viewbag ??

Comment: No tendrías que iterar `Model.vVentas`? por lo que veo, la variable `model` posee un objeto no una lista

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que estas iterando el objeto `XdSite.Models.Companis` en lugar de la propiedad `vVentas`, por otro lado, en Razor (por lo menos a mi) el loop `foreach` me ha sido conflictivo en algunas ocaciones, por eso, prefiero trabajarlo con `for`

```
@model XdSite.Models.Companis
@using XdSite.Configuration;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ventas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View.cshtml";
}

@for (int i = 0 ; i<Model.vVentas.Count() ; i++)
{
    <li><a href="/Company/@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.vVentas[i].IdeInforme)/@Cleanurls.ToFriendlyUrl(@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.vVentas[i].Nombre))" title="@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Ventas[i].Nombre)">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.vVentas[i].Nombre)</a></li>

}
```

Perdón si hay algún error de sintaxis, no tengo visual studio en estos momentos

saludos!